# how can I export react to word document

Tags: reactjs, ms-word, export, docx

I have a React app and I want to export some html content to word document and download it.
for example:

```
<div> Hello World!!!</div>
<input type="button" onClick={exportToWord()}/>
```

I search for a function that will handle a word document with the text Hello world!!!.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `redocx` library for `word documents` with `React` 
you can install redocx by NPM

```
npm i redocx
```

this simple example will render Hello World in `word doc`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, Document, Text } from 'redocx'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Document>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </Document>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, `${__dirname}/example.docx`)
```

> for Demo you can clone this repo and run locally

```
git clone https://github.com/nitin42/redocx.git
cd redocx
npm install
npm run example
```

you can find all documentation here [redocx docs](https://github.com/nitin42/redocx/tree/master/docs)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [docx npm package](https://docx.js.org/#/?id=welcome)

Here is a button onClick callback example:

```
async function exportToWord() {
    const doc = new Document({
        sections: [{
            properties: {},
            children: [
                new Paragraph({
                    children: [
                        new TextRun("Hello World")
                    ],
                 }),
            ],
         }]
    });
    const buffer = await Packer.toBuffer(doc);
    const blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"});
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'my.docx';
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't convert a react component to word docs

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-to-word-doc-docx-using-javascript/

```
 function Export2Word(filename = "") {
    var preHtml =
      "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";

    var html = preHtml + dom + postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", html], {
      type: "application/msword",
    });

    // Specify link url
    var url =
      "data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(html);

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename ? filename + ".doc" : "document.doc";

    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = url;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```